# Why the draggable plugin does not work for a radar chart in ChartJS?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Currently I am building a frontend application, that uses data like AirQuality and information about POIs. For displaying the rating of the single points I am using a radar chart with ChartJS (using it the First Time ever!).

I can already change the chart with input data, that is pushed to the chart after a button click. Another functionality I wanted to implement is the possibility to drag the endpoints of the radar chart to change the values.

I found the [draggable plugin](https://github.com/compwright/chartjs-plugin-draggable) and I have tried to implement it, but it does not work like I thought it would.

This is the first time I am working with chartJS and I have found myself confused with the documentation about the plugin.

I am using plain JavaScript. No frameworks at all.

Here is the code for my chart:

```
 var data = {
  labels: ["Air", "POI", "Noise"],
    datasets: [{
        backgroundColor: "#50237f",
        borderColor: "#50237f",
        data: [33.3333333333, 33.3333333333, 33.3333333333],
        label: 'Rating'
    }]
};

var options = {
  scale: {
    ticks: {
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      stepSize: 25,
      showLabelBackdrop: false
    }
  },
    maintainAspectRatio: true,
    spanGaps: false,
    elements: {
        line: {
            tension: 0.000001
        }
    },

};

var ctx = document.getElementById("ratingChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'radar',
    data: data,
    options: options,
  config: {
    plugins: {
      // maybe set the plugin here? but how?
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: tried to implement the plugin. but it did not work.